# Splitting a string comes from HTML textarea cause give unexpected result in GOLANG

Tags: html, string, go, split

I have a string variable **str** that holds a value that

[image: my textarea]

comes from HTML texarea

and I am trying to split the string by new line

```
fmt.Println("befor split:")
    fmt.Println(str)
    x := strings.Split(str, "\n")
fmt.Println("after split:")
    fmt.Println(x)
```

and this is wat i got

[image: the result i got]

Comment: The string probably contains a `\r`. Print the string with `fmt.Printf("%q\n", str)` to view the control characters in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different types of line endings: Depending on the platform, a newline can be represented as \r\n (Windows), \n (Unix/Linux), or \r (Old Mac).

```
const textareaValue = document.getElementById("yourTextareaId").value;
const lines = textareaValue.split(/\r?\n/); // This will handle both \r\n and \n
```